# I'm trying to parse hashtags via re.findall() in python but adjacent hashtags are excluded

Tags: python

I'm trying to parse hashtags from my users input data in order to convert the obtained strings (titles) into `<a>` tags if they are present in my database. Basically I want my websites users to be able to mention other titles in their entries.

Later on I will also do the same for "@" sign.

```
    a="lşkdjflkgtitle10#title5jdflkgjdlkf*jg lkp&fjgld#title34 kjgdl #fkgjdlfkj^#title10 "

    title= re.findall("#(.*?)[\s|#|@|$)]",a)
    print(title)
```

But I couldn't get re.findall to parse the second hashtag if there is no other sign separating two hashtags.

result:

['title5jdflkgjdlkf*jg', 'title34', 'fkgjdlfkj^']

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use "[look ahead](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)" to prevent the previous match from consuming the hash sign from the next match.

This code should work with all your tags:

```
import re

a = u"lşkdjflkgtitle10#title5jdflkgjdlkf*jg lkp&fjgld#title34 kjgdl #fkgjdlfkj^#title10 "

title = re.findall(r"[#@]([^\s#@$]*)(?=[\s#@$])", a)

print(title)
```

Comment: @bourplan You are welcome. One thing I forgot to mention: you don't need '|' (or) in a character class '[]'. These brackets already act like 'or' matching any single character from the list inside.

Comment: Yes I understood that after reading your first answer. I kind of felt that the function was ignoring the character at which previous string ends but I didn't know where to look at to find a solution as  it's my first time encountering regex. Both of your answers helped me a lot, thanks again.